# Circular dendrogram with Altair

Tags: python, visualization, altair, vega, dendrogram

I'm trying to build a circular dendrogram with **Python**.

This example from Vega is perfect: https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/radial-tree-layout/

But after several days, I've been unable to reproduce it with **Altair**.

Is it because of Vega-lite? Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: You cannot build that with Altair. Altair uses Vega-Lite which doesn't have the appropriate transforms. You'll need to use Vega.

Comment: Vega is only JS lib, isn't it?

Comment: You can display Vega code directly via IPython, as is detailed in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74786313/how-to-use-vega-vega-lite-specs-in-altair-e-g-to-create-a-circle-packing-plot